# JavaScript: алгоритм создания карты HTML-заголовков (<h1>-<h6>)

Tags: javascript, html

Есть статья, в которой присутствуют HTML-заголовки (`<h1>-<h6>`).

Как составить карту (алгоритм), подобную той, которую создаёт Nu Html Checker?

[Пример](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fw3.org&showoutline=yes)

[image: Nu Html Checker Outline]

Такая карта  нужна для быстрой навигации по статье и будет размещаться во фиксированном боковом меню.

Comment: [Рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: @zb', не всё так просто или я не уловил вашу мысль. В общем, я придумал решение,.. через координаты в документе — как обкатаю (оно работает, но хочу допилить и добавить некоторые моменты), так выложу.

Comment: Можно ссылаться на id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм следующий:

- получаем заголовки в указанном элементе;
- cортируем их по `pageYOffset`;
- генерируем разметку.

```js
var from = document.getElementById('from');
var to = document.getElementById('to');

var headers = [];

// Получаем заголовки в указанном элементе

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  var headersOnPage = from.querySelectorAll('h' + i);
  for (var j = 0; j < headersOnPage.length; j++) {
    headers.push(headersOnPage[j]);
  }
}

// Сортируем их по `pageYOffset`

var sortedHeaders = {};
headers.forEach(function(header) {
  sortedHeaders[
    Math.round(header.getBoundingClientRect().top + pageYOffset)
  ] = header;
});
headers = sortedHeaders;

// Генерируем разметку

var nav = document.createElement('nav');
nav.classList.add('header-map');

for (var header in headers) {
  var item = document.createElement('div');
  item.classList.add(
    'header-map-' + headers[header].tagName.toLowerCase()
  );
  item.textContent = headers[header].textContent;
  nav.appendChild(item);
}

to.appendChild(nav);
```

```css
.header-map-h2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="to"></div>

<hr>

<div id="from">

  <h1>Header 1 - Section 1</h1>
  <h2>Header 2.1 - Section 1</h2>
  <h2>Header 2.2 - Section 1</h2>

  <h1>Header 1 - Section 2</h1>
  <h2>Header 2.1 - Section 2</h2>
  <h2>Header 2.2 - Section 2</h2>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qmgd3ouv

Comment: элементы и так получаются в порядке расположения в разметке. Хм, да и сортировки в коде вообще нет.

Comment: @Grundy, так, сейчас и не вспомню зачем это нужно было, но помню, что нужно было ) Я написал это давно, а сейчас перебираю свои старые записи и вот выложил. Вспомню — отпишу.

Comment: @Grundy, дело в том, что в `heades` сначала помещаются заголовки `h1`, затем `h2` и так далее, поэтому их нужно отсортировать; а чтобы их отсортировать, мы используем объект: *если имя свойства – число или числовая строка, то все современные браузеры сортируют такие свойства в целях внутренней оптимизации* (https://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in#в-каком-порядке-перебираются-свойства).

Comment: "Сортировка" будет только положительных чисел из диапазона для int32, если вдруг будет отрицательное или дробное - то такая сортировка сломается

Comment: Поэтому лучше все-таки использовать стандартный метод sort :-)